# Image of Upper Unit Semi Circle under Joukowsky Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I'm trying to understand how the Joukowski Transformation would map the following region:

$$\{z|0<arg(z)<\pi , |z|<1\}$$

with the Joukowski Transformation being : $w = \frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$

I know that the transformation maps the boundary of the unit circle on the $[-1,1]$ segment on the real axis of the $w$-plane but I don't know how to find the rest.

Any thought?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Parametrize
$$x=\cos\theta,$$
$$y=\sin\theta,$$
where $0\le\theta\le2\pi$ for the complex number $z=x+iy$.

Then try to separate the Re and Im parts of
$\dfrac{1}{2}\left(x+iy+\dfrac{1}{x+iy}\right)$.

Comment: I did it like you said and found that the Im part is 0 and Re is just $\cos (\theta)$ so basically it maps it on the -1 to 1 segment on the real axis.

Comment: Glad to "hear" that : ) , thank you

Comment: Additionally if you take $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ then $x^2+y^2=1$ and $$\dfrac{1}{2}\left(x+i\sqrt{1-x^2}+x-i\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)=x$$